# Video Plays on all browsers except firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, html5-video

my website seems to behave in odd way in firefox.
this is the [website](http://beiraq.ir)
2 odd things happens in ff:

1. I have a div which has some problem with its style:

   this is the style:

   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-35%);
   transform: translate(-50%,-35%);
   -moz-transform: translate(-50%,65%);

this div normally looks not it its excepted position in ff. I fixed this one with -moz- prefix which doesn't looks the right thing to do.

2. the background video is not playing in ff at all.
   but plays good in all other browsers
   check it [here](http://beiraq.ir).

Comment: I would remove all code but the playing bit and test in FF. When working ok, I'd add a piece of code at a time and retest.

Comment: Since you are already having `left: 50%` , you probably move it off the screen (or at least very far to the right) with the `65%` value in `-moz-transform: translate`

Answer (score 0):

What format is the video you are trying to play? Did you try .ogg format? For center positioning the div try flex like this:

```
body, html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.your-div-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

This will work better across all browsers.

Comment: mp4, its playing ok on ff when I remove the css file.

Comment: Your video has a container of 0px height and width, so when you set `oveflow: hidden` in `.VideoDiv`, it gets completely hidden. You should either remove `overflow: hidden` in `.VideoDiv`, or set `height: 100%` and `width: 100%` in your video container. Hope this helps.